# Combining successive and treatment contrasts in lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme, categorical-encoding, contrasts

I am running a lmer mixed effects model with three fixed effects parameters, each having multiple levels:

predic1: HH LR RR LD (4 levels)
predic3: L1 L2 L3 L4 (4 levels)
predic2: A B C D E F (5 levels)

I know that R, by default, uses the treatment coding for contrasts, where each level is compared to a reference level. I would instead like to have access to all the possible pairwise comparisons between different levels of each predictor. For example, in the case of predic1, I would like to see the following comparisons in the results of the model:

(HH-LR) 1-2
(HH-RR) 1-3
(HH-LD) 1-4
(LR-RR) 2-3
(LR-LD) 2-4
(RR-LD) 3-4

More like a combination of successive and treatment contrast codings.

Is there any built-in function in R for this type of comparison? If not what is the correct contrast matrix for these comparisons?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed do all multiple comparisons between the levels of these predictors, and appropriately correct for multiple testing. This can be done, with, for instance, the **multcomp** and **emmeans** packages. Below a generic example with **multcomp**:

```
library(multcomp)

fm <- lmer(...) 

fm_mc <- glht(fm, linfct = mcp(predic1 = "Tukey"))
summary(fm_mc)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tired multicomp based on your suggestion. I’m afraid the results are not consistent with those of lmerTest. The reason is that lmerTest uses a different method (Satterthwaite’s method of approximation) to calculate p-values.

Comment: You can set the degrees of freedom for the $t$ distribution (e.g., what you get from the **lmerTest**) in `glht()` using the `df` argument.